# changing pdf page Sliding effect in PDFKitten example objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am stuck here. i want to change sliding effect in this example.

i don't know where to change this effect settings.

in this example, everything works fine except scrolling of pages.

you can find example here: [PDFKITTEN EXAMPLE GITHUB](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten)

i want to change page scrolling effect. it is left to right or vice versa.

i want to make it just same as we are reading book and scrolling page.

i have tried to change following code in pageView

```
if (currentPage.detailedView)
 {
[UIView transitionFromView:currentPage.detailedView toView:currentPage    duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    completion:nil];
 currentPage.detailedView = nil;
 return;
}

currentPage.detailedView = detailedView;
detailedView.frame = currentPage.frame;
[UIView transitionFromView:currentPage toView:detailedView duration:1.0    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

and changed to this code:

```
 if (currentPage.detailedView)
     {
     [UIView transitionFromView:currentPage.detailedView toView:currentPage duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];
  currentPage.detailedView = nil;
     return;
    }


currentPage.detailedView = detailedView;
detailedView.frame = currentPage.frame;
[UIView transitionFromView:currentPage toView:detailedView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];
```

but i did not get success. what am i missing?

Can Any one help me with this example ?

Comment: provide some code what you have tried

Comment: i have been trying to change everything. but could not get success. try this example. https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF